# Упрощение выражения с помощью list comprehension

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

Возможно ли сделать всё это в одной строчке в виде list comprehension?

```
field = [["1" for _ in range(2)] for _ in range(5)]
for a in range(5):
    field[a].insert(random.randint(0, 2), "0")
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конкретно ваш код с методом `insert` невозможно записать в виде `list comprehenshion`, поскольку `insert`, а так же `append` и ещё другие методы изменяют исходный список, а не возвращают новый, поэтому если мы захотим написать как-то так:

```
field = [["1" for _ in range(2)].insert(random.randint(0, 2), "0") for _ in range(5)]
print(field)
```

То мы ожидаемо увидим вывод:

```
[None, None, None, None, None]
```

Но вполне можно написать другой код, который делает то же самое.

Например, так:

```
import itertools
import random

field = [list(x) for x in random.choices(list(itertools.permutations(['1', '1', '0'])), k=5)]

print(field)
```

Тогда мы увидим нужный нам результат:

```
[['1', '1', '0'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['1', '1', '0'], ['1', '0', '1'], ['0', '1', '1']]
```

Comment: Всё бы хорошо, но `x for x in ` тут вообще лишнее, так что это списочное сокращение тут искусственно приделано )  Но по сути вариант самый оптимальный

Comment: @CrazyElf вообще да)) если человек хочет comprehenshion, то приделаем, а на самом деле и не нужен)

Comment: `random.choices(tuple(itertools.permutations('110')), k=5)`.

Comment: @CrazyElf хотя там перестановки то возвращают тапл, а у человека были листы, поэтому логично их преобразовать как раз)

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy а в чём ключевое различие?

Comment: Нет ключевых различий. Так короче писать.

Answer (score 3):

можно сразу заготовить все три варианта и выбирать случайный

```
field = [list(['110', '101', '011'][random.randint(0, 2)]) for _ in range(5)]
```

Comment: эх, во как точно

Comment: вот так хорошо))

Comment: Вот я хотел и такое что-то сделать, но не додумал ))

Comment: @CrazyElf я тоже не сразу. пока с другим ковырялся, придумалось

Comment: `[list(c) for c in random.choices(('011', '101', '110'), k=5)]`

Comment: тоже хороший вариант

Answer (score 2):

Получилось не очень красиво, но да, можно записать это всё в списочное сокращение, если использовать срезы:

```
field = [(lambda x: ['1','1'][:x]+['0']+['1','1'][x:])(random.randint(0, 2)) for _ in range(5)]
```

Пример вывода:

```
[['1', '1', '0'],
 ['1', '1', '0'],
 ['0', '1', '1'],
 ['1', '0', '1'],
 ['1', '0', '1']]
```

Comment: Красиво!) Но формально всё равно код не его, а решающий аналогичную задачу)

Comment: @Павел Ну, по факту это тот же `insert`, но "вручную" )  У вас, конечно, наиболее правильный вариант по сути. Хотя...

Answer (score 2):

random.sample нам в помощь:

```
from random import sample

[sample([1,0], 3, counts=[2,1]) for _ in range(5)]

>>>
[[0, 1, 1], [1, 1, 0], [1, 1, 0], [1, 0, 1], [0, 1, 1]]
```